# How to stop a Postgrex process and its TypeServer process?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, postgrex

I have a few thousand databases. I want to connect to each of them in series one by one and issue a query. I do this by starting a Postgrex process like this for each one.

```
  {:ok, pid} =
    Postgrex.start_link(
      port: database.port,
      hostname: database.host,
      username: database.username,
      password: database.password,
      database: database.database_name
    )
```

I then issue a `Postgrex.query`, and then stop it like this

```
  :ok = GenServer.stop(pid, :normal)
```

Everything seems to work fine, except that I end up with thousands of `Postgrex.TypeServer` processes eating up memory that don't seem to get cleaned up for quite a while.

Is there a better way to clean up a `Postgrex` process so that the `TypeServer` is also stopped?

I'm on Postgrex 0.13.3.

EDIT:

To clarify things a bit, I'd like to clean up the TypeServer after each Postgrex process is stopped. Cleaning up all the TypeServers after the entire Enum.map is done is not all that useful to me because it results in memory slowly growing followed by a sharp drop rather than a flat line.

```
Enum.map(databases, fn database ->
  {:ok, pid} = Postgrex.start_link(port: database.port, hostname: database.host, username: database.username, password: database.password, database: database.database_name)   
  Postgrex.query!(pid, "some query", [])
  :ok = GenServer.stop(pid, :normal)
  # something here to clean up the TypeServer
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not dig it till the very bottom, but `Postgrex.TypeServer`s [are managed by](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/7519789b21d0b4a5d621952e8ed5e0acf8355ebf/lib/postgrex/type_supervisor.ex#L32-L35) dynamic `Postgrex.TypeSupervisor`, that is luckily [started with a hard-coded name](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/7519789b21d0b4a5d621952e8ed5e0acf8355ebf/lib/postgrex/type_supervisor.ex#L13-L15).

So my wild guess would be the following should do:

```rb
DynamicSupervisor.stop(Postgrex.TypeSupervisor)
```

Also, shutting down [`Postgrex.App`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/7519789b21d0b4a5d621952e8ed5e0acf8355ebf/lib/postgrex/app.ex) should also help

```rb
Application.stop(:postgrex)
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksei! Would that affect other postgrex processes that may be running? According to what I'm seeing a TypeServer is started for every Postgrex process so I only want to shutdown the one TypeServer associated with the Postgrex process rather than all of them.

Comment: Instead of stopping the whole process, you might collect the PIDs of your `TypeServer`s and then iterate over them calling [`DynamicSupervisor.terminate_child/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html#terminate_child/2) on each. Or something alike.

Comment: Thanks Aleksei. I edited the question with a clarification, could you take a look?